# OptaPlanner log solver phase change

Tags: optaplanner

I have an OptaPlanner project wit a solver configured in phases as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<solver>
    ...
    <!--    SOLVER PHASES CONFIGURATION -->
    <!-- First phase: First Fit Decreasing -->
    <constructionHeuristic>
        <constructionHeuristicType>FIRST_FIT</constructionHeuristicType>
    </constructionHeuristic>
    <!-- Second phase: Tabu Search -->
    <localSearch>
        <localSearchType>TABU_SEARCH</localSearchType>
        <termination>
            <terminationCompositionStyle>OR</terminationCompositionStyle>
            <minutesSpentLimit>2</minutesSpentLimit>
            <unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>20</unimprovedSecondsSpentLimit>
            <bestScoreLimit>0hard/0medium/0soft</bestScoreLimit>
        </termination>
    </localSearch>
    ...
</solver>
```

I would like to log the change of phase. Is it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Please see [OptaPlanner documentation on logging](https://docs.optaplanner.org/latest/optaplanner-docs/html_single/index.html#logging).